# Can SFDC Approval process be Exposed to web service?

Tags: web-services, configuration, workflow, salesforce

The [SalesForce](http://salesforce.com/) Approval Process goes through steps. For each step user can "Approve" / "Reject" it.
Is there any way that when it goes to step, a web service can expose it and someone from outside can approve it or reject it without entering into SalesForce?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

It's easy (if a bit tedious) to expose info about currently pending approvals. Easiest way is to run the report stored under "Administrative Reports", you can also examine & query `ProcessInstance*` tables.

It's easy to salvage the usage of `Approval` class to create Apex code that can be used to approve/reject from sample unit test: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm

So you should have all the tools to build a webservice that displays them & lets you approve. The problem is that if you'll use hardcoded credentials of "integration user" it will be displayed as actual approver everywhere instead of designated user. And if they have to provide their credentials to your other website - that's almost as tedious as logging in to SF, you might just build a Visualforce page for them ;)

Read the docs about approval processes, there's also an option to approve by replying to the notification email with "YES" in the body and this one-time mailbox will do all the magic.

Comment: it means you have to create web service for approve or reject..rite ? I want to expose this service on mobile app where it will send Approve/Reject response...Please suggest if this is possible..

Comment: I'd say so. Bit of Apex, exposed as SOAP webservice or REST (better suited for mobile). Try running updates on the `ProcessInstanceWorkItem` etc records but if it won't work you have to use this `Approval` class... In fact this doesn't look updateable: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_processinstancestep.htm